# CentOS, install nodejs latest

Tags: centos, node.js

i have problem with installation of latest version of node on CentOS 7

i run

```
yum remove nodesource-release* nodejs
yum clean all
```

command `rpm -qa 'node|npm'` shows nothing, so i run this command:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -xe -
```

but it still wants to install `sudo yum install nodejs` >> `2:6.17.1-1nodesource` and not version 10.x

how to resolve this?

Comment: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/340#issuecomment-251417163 is answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

You probably have stale data in the yum cache, corresponding to an older version of Node.js from nodesource. You should clean it all using:

```
yum clean all
```

If that fails, you can manually delete the cache directory:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Then try the installation again.

Comment: yes i found, that and posted comment to my question